# Menu API data not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mongoose

I am trying to make API for sample Menu Data in which the data must be fetched and shown by entering Restaurant ID. Controller, Model and Router is set but I load it in Postman the data is not showing also if I `console.log()` the result, its showing an empty array. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Controller (Menu.js)

```
const Menu = require('../Models/Menu');

exports.getMenu = (req, res) => {
    Menu.find({
        restID: req.params.restID
    }).then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
            menus: result,
            message: "Menu Data Success"
        });
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
        message: error
        });
    })
}
```

Model (Menu.js)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const MenuSchema = new Schema({
    item: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cost: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    restID: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('menus', MenuSchema, 'Menu');
```

Router (router.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const MenuController = require('../Controllers/Menu');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/restaurantMenu/:restID',MenuController.getMenu);

module.exports = router;
```